# Session problem in Struts based application

Tags: session, struts, state

I am doing a multi user login application where I use session to store the user object.

```
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
  session.setAttribute("user",user);
```

In every page I am checking using JSTL whether the user object is present in the session.

```
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${not empty sessionScope.user}"> 
    //jsp code
    </c:when>
   <c:otherwise> 
    <logic:redirect forward="welcome"/>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

My problem is that if the user clicks on a href link in the application the user changes to Previous user in the session. i.e. the it is loading the user from cache. If I refresh the page it will load the correct user.

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, session is stored on server and has nothing to do with client cache.

Previous user is not loaded from cache (as you say), the page is loaded from cache since links go to the server on a GET. The browser is free to cache the result of a GET if the URL didn't change since the last time it was requested.

To fix this, you need to invalidate the client cache. You can do that by adding [HTTP cache header directives](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) or [by adding meta tags in the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers).

I would suggest to go with HTTP headers since proxies usually don't read the content of the page and you may end up with a cache on a proxy server even if the client does not store the page in the client cache.